# How to have an event check an entry to see if it matches a variable in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm wondering how to have Python check an event to see if `username` and `password` match, and then print `correct` if it is or `false` if it isn't. When I try the result is always `false`. I need a way to make it check to see if they match.

Here's my code:

```
    from tkinter import *

    root = Tk()

    def check(event):
    username = "Amras"
    password = "pass"
    if entry1 == username:
      if entry2 == password:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
    else:
        print("false")

    name = Label(root, text="Name: ")
    password = Label(root, text="Password: ")
    entry1 = Entry(root)
    entry2 = Entry(root)
    c = Checkbutton(root, text="Keep me logged in")
    button1 = Button(root, text="Login")
    button1.bind("<Button-1>", check)

    name.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
    password.grid(row=1, sticky=E)

    entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    c.grid(columnspan=2)

    button1.grid(row=1, column=2)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Instead of having two `if` statements and two `else` statements, just have `if (entry1.get() == username) and (entry2.get() == password):` and `else:`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't evaluate the text you put inside the `entry` box. Use `entry1.get()` etc...

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def check(event):
    username = "Amras"
    password = "pass"
    # Also these if statements should be combined
    if entry1.get() == username:   # Use the .get() method
      if entry2.get() == password: # Use the .get() method
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")


name = Label(root, text="Name: ")
password = Label(root, text="Password: ")
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry2 = Entry(root)
c = Checkbutton(root, text="Keep me logged in")
button1 = Button(root, text="Login")
button1.bind("<Button-1>", check)

name.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
password.grid(row=1, sticky=E)

entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)

c.grid(columnspan=2)

button1.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Not after you type `Amras` and `pass` in you should get `true`

Also in your code the import statement seems bad (`Tkinter` with a capital by default), there are two `else` statements in the definition, and the indentation is wrong as well.

Comment: okay and the indentation is from me being to lazy to correctly set it up when I was asking the question

Comment: Thats fine, but the two `else` statements may cause trouble

Comment: Also if this answer is correct, and solved your problem, please mark it as correct